# Change hover style within Twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I have this pure-CSS (display) solution for a follow button:

```
<span class="follow-status following">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-follow" data-user-id="123">
        <span class="following-text"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Following</span>
        <span class="follow-text"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Follow</span>
        <span class="unfollow-text"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Unfollow</span>
    </a>
</span>
```

I'd like to, for example, change the text on hover depending on what shows up. However the a element has the padding, and stylizing the span looks really awkward.
- Should I overwrite the A padding and shift it into the span?
- Should I write the HTML differently?
- Should I just toggle applicable text/style by JS?
- Something else?

you can see the outer span has the class "following"

```
.follow-status span { display:none }
.following .following-text { display: block}
.following:hover .following-text { display: none}
.following:hover .unfollow-text { display: block}
```

how would you accompliush that within the twitter bootstrap confines?

Comment: why does stylizing the span look awkward?

Comment: Only an inner portion would get the background color, for example. The outside would get the default gray. And hte background color depends on the span/text being shown...

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would remove all padding/margins from the spans inside the anchor and apply your CSS padding/margins etc to the anchor element. That way you future proof yourself incase you want to add different elements inside the anchor element.